# Invalid system call error when executing file command

Tags: shell, system-calls, seccomp

I noticed a strange thing. When I run the `file` command as a regular user, I always get an invalid system call error.

For example in [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh):

```
$ file ~/.zshrc

[1]    18553 invalid system call  file ~/.zshrc
```

Or in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) / [dash](/questions/tagged/dash) / [sh](/questions/tagged/sh):

```
$ file ~/.bashrc

Bad system call
```

It does not depend on the target file, wm environment (happens in tty as well) and seems to not depend on the shell either.

The only way to avoid this error is to run the command as a root or with `sudo`:

```
$ sudo file ~/.bashrc                                                                        

/home/user/.bashrc: ASCII text
```

It doesn't look like expected behaviour. Does anyone know what can cause this issue?

I have no idea how to proceed in debugging this. Any comment or link could be useful because I didn't find anything related directly to the `file` command, which seems to be only one command affected by this.

**Edit 1**

`ls` and `df` commands work as expected.

```
$ ls -alGg .bashrc

-rw-r--r-- 1 603 31. led 11.09 .bashrc

$ df -h .
        
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p5  420G  419G  1.5G 100% /home
```

`file` command I use:

```
$ whereis file

file: /usr/bin/file /usr/share/man/man1/file.1.bz2 /usr/share/man/man1p/file.1p.bz2 /usr/share/man/mann/file.n.bz2
```

```
$ which file

/usr/bin/file
```

```
$ command -v file

/usr/bin/file
```

```
$ file -v

file-5.39
magic file from /usr/share/misc/magic
seccomp support included
```

**Edit 2**

I use Gentoo and figured out that when I compile [`file`](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/sys-apps/file) package without [`seccomp`](https://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/tree/sys-apps/file/file-5.39-r3.ebuild#n64) USE flag, it works fine.

**Edit 3**

```
$ strace file ~/.bashrc

execve("/usr/bin/file", ["file", "/home/user/.bashrc"], 0x7fff74d08c58 /* 74 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55e04e3e3000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\270\3\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1857608, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff54a543000
mmap(NULL, 1867584, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff54a37b000
mprotect(0x7ff54a3b3000, 1593344, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7ff54a3b3000, 1040384, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x38000) = 0x7ff54a3b3000
mmap(0x7ff54a4b1000, 548864, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x136000) = 0x7ff54a4b1000
mmap(0x7ff54a538000, 40960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bc000) = 0x7ff54a538000
mmap(0x7ff54a542000, 3904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff54a542000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\315\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1201032, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1206440, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff54a254000
mprotect(0x7ff54a270000, 1081344, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7ff54a270000, 532480, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c000) = 0x7ff54a270000
mmap(0x7ff54a2f2000, 544768, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x9e000) = 0x7ff54a2f2000
mmap(0x7ff54a378000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x123000) = 0x7ff54a378000
mmap(0x7ff54a37a000, 2216, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff54a37a000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=218596, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 218596, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff54a21e000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/libmagic.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0PG\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=158712, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 161688, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff54a1f6000
mmap(0x7ff54a1fa000, 102400, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4000) = 0x7ff54a1fa000
mmap(0x7ff54a213000, 36864, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1d000) = 0x7ff54a213000
mmap(0x7ff54a21c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7ff54a21c000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/libseccomp.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320Q\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=309280, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 311568, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff54a1a9000
mmap(0x7ff54a1ce000, 40960, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7ff54a1ce000
mmap(0x7ff54a1d8000, 16384, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2f000) = 0x7ff54a1d8000
mmap(0x7ff54a1dc000, 106496, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x32000) = 0x7ff54a1dc000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0@\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1798224, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1811664, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff549fee000
mmap(0x7ff54a010000, 1327104, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x22000) = 0x7ff54a010000
mmap(0x7ff54a154000, 307200, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x166000) = 0x7ff54a154000
mmap(0x7ff54a19f000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b0000) = 0x7ff54a19f000
mmap(0x7ff54a1a5000, 13520, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff54a1a5000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@\347\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=379696, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 384776, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff549f90000
mmap(0x7ff549f9e000, 212992, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xe000) = 0x7ff549f9e000
mmap(0x7ff549fd2000, 98304, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x42000) = 0x7ff549fd2000
mmap(0x7ff549fea000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x59000) = 0x7ff549fea000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@\22\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=18472, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff549f8e000
mmap(NULL, 20888, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff549f88000
mmap(0x7ff549f89000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7ff549f89000
mmap(0x7ff549f8b000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7ff549f8b000
mmap(0x7ff549f8c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7ff549f8c000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0203\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=100592, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 102800, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff549f6e000
mmap(0x7ff549f71000, 57344, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7ff549f71000
mmap(0x7ff549f7f000, 28672, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x11000) = 0x7ff549f7f000
mmap(0x7ff549f86000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x7ff549f86000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libmount.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\332\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=382776, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 385800, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff549f0f000
mprotect(0x7ff549f1b000, 327680, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7ff549f1b000, 245760, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xc000) = 0x7ff549f1b000
mmap(0x7ff549f57000, 77824, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x48000) = 0x7ff549f57000
mmap(0x7ff549f6b000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5b000) = 0x7ff549f6b000
mmap(0x7ff549f6d000, 776, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff549f6d000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260C\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=84528, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 96896, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff549ef7000
mprotect(0x7ff549efb000, 65536, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7ff549efb000, 49152, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4000) = 0x7ff549efb000
mmap(0x7ff549f07000, 12288, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x10000) = 0x7ff549f07000
mmap(0x7ff549f0b000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x13000) = 0x7ff549f0b000
mmap(0x7ff549f0d000, 6784, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff549f0d000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360k\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=148000, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 128088, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff549ed7000
mmap(0x7ff549edd000, 61440, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7ff549edd000
mmap(0x7ff549eec000, 20480, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15000) = 0x7ff549eec000
mmap(0x7ff549ef1000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19000) = 0x7ff549ef1000
mmap(0x7ff549ef3000, 13400, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff549ef3000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libpcre.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360!\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=460856, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 463336, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff549e65000
mmap(0x7ff549e67000, 327680, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7ff549e67000
mmap(0x7ff549eb7000, 122880, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x52000) = 0x7ff549eb7000
mmap(0x7ff549ed5000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6f000) = 0x7ff549ed5000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libbz2.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=74904, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff549e63000
mmap(NULL, 77192, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff549e50000
mmap(0x7ff549e52000, 53248, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7ff549e52000
mmap(0x7ff549e5f000, 8192, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xf000) = 0x7ff549e5f000
mmap(0x7ff549e61000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x10000) = 0x7ff549e61000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/libffi.so.7", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=43280, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 46728, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff549e44000
mprotect(0x7ff549e46000, 32768, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7ff549e46000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7ff549e46000
mmap(0x7ff549e4c000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x8000) = 0x7ff549e4c000
mmap(0x7ff549e4e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x9000) = 0x7ff549e4e000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\21\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=14320, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 16656, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff549e3f000
mmap(0x7ff549e40000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7ff549e40000
mmap(0x7ff549e41000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7ff549e41000
mmap(0x7ff549e42000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7ff549e42000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libblkid.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\237\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=328408, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 331432, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff549dee000
mmap(0x7ff549df7000, 208896, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x9000) = 0x7ff549df7000
mmap(0x7ff549e2a000, 65536, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3c000) = 0x7ff549e2a000
mmap(0x7ff549e3a000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4b000) = 0x7ff549e3a000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff549dec000
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff549de9000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ff549de9740) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff54a19f000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff549e3a000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff549e42000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff549e4e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff549e61000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff549ef1000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff549ed5000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff549f0b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff549f6b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff549f86000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff54a378000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff549f8c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff549fea000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff54a1dc000, 102400, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff54a21c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff54a538000, 28672, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55e04d057000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ff54a56f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7ff54a21e000, 218596)          = 0
set_tid_address(0x7ff549de9a10)         = 20864
set_robust_list(0x7ff549de9a20, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7ff549edd650, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7ff549ee9820}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7ff549edd6f0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7ff549ee9820}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55e04e3e3000
brk(0x55e04e404000)                     = 0x55e04e404000
futex(0x7ff54a37a618, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7ff54a37a618, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=225035648, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 225035648, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff53c74c000
close(3)                                = 0
prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS, 1, 0, 0, 0)  = 0
prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, SUID_DUMP_DISABLE) = 0
prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS, 1, 0, 0, 0)  = 0
seccomp(SECCOMP_SET_MODE_STRICT, 1, NULL) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
seccomp(SECCOMP_SET_MODE_FILTER, 0, 0x55e04e3f0760) = 0
stat(0x55e04e3f0b30, 0x7ffc52d15900)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat(0x55e04e3f0b30, 0x7ffc52d15900)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, 0x55e04e3f4270, O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, 0x7ffc52d159e0)                = 0
mmap(NULL, 6652192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff53c0f3000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7ff53c0f3000, 6652192, PROT_READ) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, 0x7ff54a1724d0, O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, 0x7ffc52d15710)                = 0
mmap(NULL, 26988, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7ff54a24d000
close(3)                                = 0
futex(0x7ff54a1a4974, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = ?
+++ killed by SIGSYS +++
[1]    20861 invalid system call  strace file ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: What do commands such as `ls -la` and `df -h .` show?

Comment: When I run this I get: `file ~/.bashrc    ~/.bashrc: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable`.  My guess is a strange shebang.  What's the output of `$ head -n 1 ~/.bashrc`?  Mine is `#!/bin/bash`.  If yours is the same, does `/bin/bash` exist?

Comment: looks like you are not using a "good" version of file, what do `whereis file`, `command -v file`, `which file` and `type file` show ?

Comment: I edited the post to address your comments. As I already said @Stewart, it does not depend on the file and works fine with sudo.

Comment: You left out `command -v file`, which is the most important of the above commands to figure out what’s going on.

Comment: @Stewart `.bashrc` shouldn’t have a shebang at all, it’s not run as a standalone script.

Comment: I edited my post @StephenKitt

Comment: Thanks! I guess it’s time to whip `strace` out: what does `strace file ~/.bashrc` say, as a regular user?

Comment: @StephenKitt I found out and `strace` output confirmed it, it is somehow related to seccomp / libseccomp.

Comment: Nice, so it looks like you’ve got enough to write an answer (even if it’s not complete)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `strace file ~/.bashrc`:

```
seccomp(SECCOMP_SET_MODE_STRICT, 1, NULL) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
seccomp(SECCOMP_SET_MODE_FILTER, 0, 0x55e04e3f0760) = 0
stat(0x55e04e3f0b30, 0x7ffc52d15900)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat(0x55e04e3f0b30, 0x7ffc52d15900)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

One solution for me is to compile [sys-apps/file](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/sys-apps/file) package with disabled `seccomp` USE flag. Another one is to compile the package with enabled `seccomp` and `lzma` USE flags together.

From `equery uses file`:

```
lzma    : Support for LZMA (de)compression algorithm

seccomp : Enable seccomp (secure computing mode) to perform system call 
          filtering at runtime to increase security of programs
```

It seems to be a bug in upstream. https://bugs.gentoo.org/771096